# while loop that is equivalent to for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to experiment how the while loop works.

```
docs = ['123867', '256789', '3aa', '4gg', '5yy', '6abc']
for i in range(0,len(docs)):
  for j in range(i,len(docs[i])):
    print(i, j)
```

My output for the above code is

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
2 2
```

I attempt to play with the while loop with

```
docs = ['123867', '256789', '3aa', '4gg', '5yy', '6abc']
i = 0
j = i
while i < len(docs):
  while j < len(docs[i]):
    print(i, j)
    j += 1
  i += 1
```

but the output is

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
```

How can I fix my while loop to match the for loop? Thanks!

Comment: Where do you initialize the `i` and `j` variables in the second example?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I just included the initialization. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Now please explain your code to [a rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) (or similar substitute, like a class-mate, room-mate, friend or relative). After the inner loop is finished what is the value of `j`? Will it ever be reset to zero again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
docs = ['123867', '256789', '3aa', '4gg', '5yy', '6abc']
i = 0
while i < len(docs):
    j = i  # should be moved here
    while j < len(docs[i]):
        print(i, j)
        j += 1
    i += 1
```